# ListView non-selected items getting selected

Tags: android, listview

I'm using multiple selection on the listview in my app which is being populated by db (`SimpleCursorAdapter`). There's some weird behavior with the listview selection.

If there are more than 7 items in the database, if I select the 1st item in the listview, the 8th item also gets selected even when I'm not selecting the 8th item and vice-versa. If I select the 9th item, the 2nd row gets selected.

What's happening here?

Code:

```
  String[] projection = { ..table_columns..};

String[] from = { table_columns..};
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(SomeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
        null);

// the XML defined views which the data will be bound to 
int[] to = new int[] { 
 R.id.color,
 R.id.name,
 R.id.desc,
};


// create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
//as well as the layout information
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
 this, R.layout.layout_main, 
 cursor, 
 from, 
 to,
 0);

dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
@Override
   public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
       int nNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(EventsTable.COLUMN_NAME);
       if( column == nNameIndex ){ 
           TextView nname = (TextView) view;
           String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EventsTable.COLUMN_NAME));

           String formatted_name = "NAME: " +name;

           nname.setText(formatted_name);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
});

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {

           if (!listView.isItemChecked(pos)){
               listView.setItemChecked(pos, true);
               v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_bg_selected));
               v.setSelected(true);

           } else {
               listView.setItemChecked(pos, false); 
               v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_bg));
               v.setSelected(false);
           }

           if (listView.getCheckedItemCount() > 0) {

               if (mMode == null) {
                   mMode = startActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());
               } else {
                   mMode.setTitle(listView.getCheckedItemCount() + " " + "Selected");

               }
           } else {
               if (mMode != null) {
                   mMode.finish();


               }
           }

           return true;
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because in your bindView of your adapter you are not checking if the item is checked, and then changing the background appropriately.

You experiencing your views being recycled.

So when you scroll, and say item one goes out of view and was selected, the view for item 1 is reused for item 8.

SO add something like this to your view binder

```
       int post = cursor.getPosition();
       if (!listView.isItemChecked(pos)){
               v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_bg_selected));

       } else {
               v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_bg));
       }
```

Comment: How do I check in bindView if the item is checked? Please check my code, I have updated it. I am not using a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: added code example. the code is similar to how you set the background in the first place. Check the status, and set or unset it based on the data.

It is very important to unset, because the recycle view may have had it's view set to reflect selection.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. But oddly enough, I lost the styling.